# How to generate a .ipa for my flutter project on MacOS without a real iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ipa

I am new to Flutter. I have developed a project using flutter for both ios and android using android studio on my macOS. I don't have a real time ios device with me but I want to share this app with my colleagues. How can I generate a .ipa for my project similar to a .apk?

Answer (score 1):

Just run  `flutter build ipa`

It builds an iOS archive bundle (Mac OS X host only).

You can get more info running `flutter build ipa -h`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't create .ipa file with out a Mac ,there are some online Mac server u can use it by paying for 1 hr like that ,but believe me that would not work

Comment: I do have a mac what I don't have is an iOS device to build my .ipa

Comment: are there any solutions in the market right now which allows you to build ios app with a device

Comment: you do not need a real device to build a .ipa file

Comment: just open your protein xcode and under product Click archive, Xcode will build ur .ipa file and then export the file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to buy a used phone on Amazon / Ebay / BackMarket etc.
I did it, some apps required physical device for test because some features are not avalable on emulator and differ from Android.